# parsing fixed length file with Regex

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I'm parsing fixed length file with .NET 3.5 and Regex. This file is from bank. In customer name sometimes there is one characters from this set `&,(),[],',""`. These are characters, so far I've encountered. There can be anything else. Because of this my regex is failing. My regex is `[A-Za-z0-9\s-\.,'""""\(\)\{\}\[\]]{35}`. Is there any wild card I can use for special chars rather than specifying individually. I also tried `.` but didn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It depends on your definition of "special chars" or "anything else". `.` (dot) is supposed to match anything, except maybe a newline, so i don't understand why "didn't work". Can you be more specific about what you wanna do. [Stack Overflow is not a Mind Reader](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128551/183347)

Comment: I know it is not mind reader. You don't need to mention that. I'm wondering if there is any wild card character that I can use in the anticipation of special chars.

Comment: By any chance, is this question a follow-up to this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034155/parse-text-file

Answer (score 0):

Your regex specifies exactly 35 occurrences of your character class, and you seem to be saying that you will accept any character as part of the name.  You say that the file is fixed length, which I interpret to mean that each line (record) is fixed length.  (The number of records in the file is likely to be variable.)  And you say that the file contains financial data.  That leads me to believe that the customer name field that you are trying to extract from the record is at a fixed character position.  If that's the case, then you don't need to use regular expressions at all, and a simple [String.Substring()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) call or something similar will serve your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Finally `.` worked. Sorry everyone. I was using wrong way. As always, thanks everyone for their time and efforts.